# Python copy file ignoring tree structure

Tags: python, copy

I need to copy files from a directory and its subdirectories to a unique destination directory, whitout reproducing the tree structure of the source directory (this means mixing together the files).

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

import os
import shutil

src  = '/Users/wiltomap/Desktop/depart/paquet'
dest = '/Users/wiltomap/Desktop/arrivee'

for dir, subdir, files in os.walk(src):
    for f in files:
        shutil.copy(f, dest)
```

...and the code doesn't work! Here is the message I get by running it in Terminal:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'paquet1.rtf'
```

'paquet1.rtf' is a file existing in subdirectory '/paquet/paquet1/'.

Thanks for help!

Comment: What do you expect to happen if there are two files with the same name in different source directories?

Comment: I don't have this issue in the present case, but it could theorically, of course! How should I take this into account in my code?

Comment: @wiltomap, it 100% depends on what you **want** to happen in such cases!  Perhaps check for duplicates and append `(1)`, then `(2)` and so forth to the destination name until a non-duplicate name is found -- that's what my browsers do when I download files with the same name, for example.

Comment: OK I understand... Thanks for your precious help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So maybe something like...:

```
for dir, subdir, files in os.walk(src):
    for f in files:
        targ = os.path.join(dest, f)
        if os.path.exists(targ):
            for i in itertools.count():
                targ = os.path.join(dest, '%s(%s)' % (f, i))
                if not os.path.exists(targ):
                    break
        shutil.copy(os.path.join(dir, f), targ)
```